# Arithmoi and phantom types

Tags: haskell, phantom-types

I'm tyring to understand the use of phantom types in the package arithmoi (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.8.0.0). It helps to check if I'm working with the right residue class (`Z/nZ`).

The phantom type in question is `data Mod (n :: Nat) = Mod Natural`, and as I understand the constructor is not exported. But the constructor of `SomeMod` is exported, so I figure I must use it to construct `::Mod n` variable.
Moreover, one can read in the documentation, but I can't use it.

```
case modulo n m of
  SomeMod k -> process k -- Here k has type Mod m
  InfMod{}  -> error "impossible"
```

So I tried:

```hs
foo :: KnownNat m => Nat -> Nat -> Mod m
foo n m = case modulo n m of
    (SomeMod k) -> k
    otherwise -> error "some error"
```

I got an error about a variable m, m1 which is escaping its scope. I'm a bit puzzled.

Comment: You might also like [Statically enforcing that two objects were created from the same (Int) “seed”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38926169/791604). While reading the question (and my answer there), when you see "seed", think "modulus"; when you see `Collection`, think `Mod`; when you see "merge collections", think "add" or "multiply" or similar such operations that only work when the moduli of the two arguments are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like IO, existentials cannot be escaped. Once in an existential, always in an existential. But that's okay -- if you're willing to admit `KnownNat m`, which your type signature claims you are willing to do, then you can just lift directly to that type.

```
foo :: KnownNat m => Natural -> Mod m
foo = fromIntegral
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, but in this case it is not possible to choose to work with modulo 2 for example. Is it impossible? If it is the case, I don't understand the purpose of having a data type such as `Mod m`

Comment: @jgrec If you cannot know the modulus at compile time -- that is, if you're not willing to admit `KnownNat m` -- then yes, you must enter existential land. Whether "it" is impossible or not depends greatly on what "it" is. You certainly cannot unwrap a `SomeMod` into a `Mod m` for any `m`, but that is almost always not the end goal anyway; serving rather as a stepping stone to some larger goal that is achievable in another way.

Comment: I'm starting to understand that a bit, but since I don't have acess to the constuctor of `Mod (::Nat)` and since I cannot transform `SomeMod` into `Mod`, how can I use `Mod x` into a programm (without knowing `x`in advance)? In `ghci` I get it, but not in a programm.

Comment: @jgrec If you do not know `x` in advance, then you do not use `Mod x`. You use `SomeMod` directly. Again: what things do you want to do with it? It's nearly impossible to answer in the abstract, but if you talk about what operations you want to do we can talk about whether/how it is possible to do those operations on `SomeMod`s.

Comment: I wanted to compute the determinant of a matrice mod x, but x must be choosen at random. But once x is choosen, I cannot use it to create mod x value. Since `SomeMod` is not an instance of `Ord`, linear arithmetic library won't be able to perform determinant computation.
Maybe I could write my own `Ord` instance for `SomeMod`? But then I would lose the benefit of restricting matrices of the same mod. With `SomeMod`, I can add/mul values mod 5 and mod 3.
In a way it seems to me that I need dependent typing, but it might not be doable.

Comment: @jgrec It should be relatively easy to cook up an `Ord` instance yourself, although I don't immediately see why it would be needed for computing a determinant. For restricting matrices to the same modulus, see the answer in the link I posted as a comment on your question above.

Comment: thanks I will try to do just that. By the way I wanted to use `detLU` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.6.1/docs/Data-Matrix.html#g:17) which requires `Ord`, but either way you're right, I can use other method to compute the determinant or I can cook myself an instance.
Thanks again